# Android RenderScript Allocation copy from NIO Direct ByteBuffer

Tags: android-ndk, nio, bytebuffer, renderscript

On Android platform (API-19) I would like to copy a direct byte buffer into a render script allocation. Is it possible to improve the following code, for example by using NDK?

```
final ByteBuffer buffer = ...src;

final byte[] bytes;
if (buffer.hasArray()) {
    bytes = buffer.array();
} else {
    bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    buffer.rewind();
}
allocation.copyFromUnchecked(bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.  The APIs are not constructed where you can provide the backing data store for the `Allocation` or even retrieve an NIO based buffer that the `Allocation` created.  The closest thing you could use would be to have a `Bitmap` based `Allocation` which was created with `USAGE_SHARED` so it could be sync'd as differences rather than a full copy.

Comment: How about using JNI? Android NDK for API-19 provides header files for the Render Script (android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/rs)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do the following:

1. Prepare your fixed size nio ByteBuffer
2. Fill the buffer in NDK (memcpy can be quite fast)
3. Use the yourAllocation.copyFromUnchecked(nioBuffer.array()) method

I hope it helps

Comment: Actually, on Android, [ByteBuffer.get(byte\[\])](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer#get(byte[])) is implemented as a fast `memcpy` whenever possible.